# No route matches [GET] "/" Devise User Sign_Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm brand new to working with Rails. I'm following the Treehouse "Build a Simple Ruby on Rails Application" tutorial. Everything was going great until just now.

I'm trying to generate the devise views but when I go to localhost:3000/users/sign_up I get an error saying

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This happens when I go to users/sign_up, users/sign_in but not when I go to users/edit

When I try to go to users/sign_up this is what the terminal spits back at me

```
    Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:16:24 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:16:24 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.6ms)
^C[2013-10-11 11:19:28] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2013-10-11 11:19:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting## Heading ##
```

When I run rake routes this is what it looks like

```
    Mikes-MacBook-Pro:treebook mike$ rake routes
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
            statuses GET    /statuses(.:format)            statuses#index
                     POST   /statuses(.:format)            statuses#create
          new_status GET    /statuses/new(.:format)        statuses#new
         edit_status GET    /statuses/:id/edit(.:format)   statuses#edit
              status GET    /statuses/:id(.:format)        statuses#show
                     PUT    /statuses/:id(.:format)        statuses#update
                     DELETE /statuses/:id(.:format)        statuses#destroy
```

I'm pretty stumped as to what to do next. Any help is super appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a root route so Rails knows where to send someone when they just open the root path.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Devise will want to redirect somewhere once you've logged in, and without a root route, it has nowhere to go.

`root to: "statuses#index"` might be a good place to start

Comment: Awesome thanks that totally worked! However now I'm having the same issue when I visit localhost:3000/users/sign_out

This is what the terminal looks like:

Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 12:11:21 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"):

Comment: It looks like /users/sign_out only takes the DELETE HTTP method. You will most likely need to create a specialized link to click rather than accessing that path directly. Something like `<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>` ought to do it.

Comment: Also, here's a full guide to adding all of the Devise-related links to a menu that shows up on all pages: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template

Answer (score 0):

Rails can not find your `root_url`.

Try adding the following to your `routes.rb` and restart your server.

`root to: '/'`

Where `root` is a helper method for your router taking the option hash `to: 'controller#action'` from one of your controllers, such as `users#index`.

The value for `to` can take a string or other ruby objects, which you will learn!

Check out this tutorial for even more ideas -> http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html